Flutter - Modify AppBar in child widget
In my Flutter app, I want to define custom AppBar actions. Methods, which will be called on that action click must be defined in child widget (in my case Page1 or Page2), because in these widgets there are Bloc providers etc., so it is not possible to define methods directly in Home widget.
I have defined Home widget as following:
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static final List<Widget> _options = <Widget>[
    const Center(child: Page1()),
    const Center(child: Page2()),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(""),
        actions: [
        ],
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(index: _selectedIndex, children: _options),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "P1", icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "P2", icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Is there any way how can I achieve that? I tried to do it with Provider, but that way isn't suitable because of IndexedStack (so when I call AppBar change in build method, it gets called only once, not every time I enter that particular page).

You could set the AppBar actions based on the _selectedIndex:
AppBar(
  title: Text(""),
    actions: [
      if(_selectedIndex == 0)
        IconButton(...),
      if(_selectedIndex == 1)
        IconButton(...),
    ],
),

To access methods from Page1 and Page2 you could use a GlobalKey as described here https://medium.com/@paalu.heing/efficient-communication-between-parent-and-child-widgets-in-flutter-c551f8e5dbeb
Through this GlobalKey you can access the current state of your page widgets. Then you could set the onPressed methods of your IconButtons to methods of your children Page1 and Page2:
final GlobalKey<Page1State> _page1Key = GlobalKey<Page1State>();
...
IconButton(
  onPressed: () => _page1Key.currentState?.onActionButtonPressed(),
)


Absolutely correct! I'll just add that this GlobalKey must be passed to the constructor of the desired page.
